# groaning noise as water stops. well water

Tags: water, noise, well

Power had gone out . wife tried using water till it stopped flowing. Now power back on but hearing a groaning noise when using the water. Is air in the line? how do I stop this noise. I do also have a acid neutralizer on the system. all was good till power when out. We have a whole house generator 18 kw. But needed to conserve propane so I shut it off at night . we were out for 5 days my propane co was closed for weekend. Now this noise is getting to me. Hope no damage is occurring. Any help in really appreciated . Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. When exactly do you hear the noise? When does it stop and start? Where does it come from?

Comment: Thanks for your response .. Seems to be when any toilet is flushed we have 2 upstairs and 1 down. . stops as soon as it fills up

Comment: Good information, but it's best if you edit it right into your question by clicking the "edit" link underneath. That way the info is all in one place. (And, if you can think of anything else to add, do so; it'll help people respond)